# Flash BIOS of rare Intel TabletPC without root-access (work-around)

Tags: linux, ssd, bios, upgrade, efi

I have a rare intel chipset based WeTab Tablet PC (actually a laptop-inside with a screen on top), it is actually similar to the ExoPC so it is possible to flash the more friendly ExoPC BIOS with boot posibilities. The specs of the device:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WeTab

However, this is a device from around 2011 and the software is really buggy and unsupported (based upon Meego Linux) and the root utility (RootShell) cannot be installed via the WeMarket app-store anymore. So it is not possible to get root access on the thing to be able to boot from USB drive to flash another BIOS.

The SSD inside this thing is replacable, so I removed the 16GB sandisk mSATA drive and replace it temporarily with an USB adapter (see below) however the EFI BIOS shows an error.

Adapter I use:

[image: mini pcie adapter]

BIOS Error:

```
EFI Shell version 2.00 [4.640]
Current running mode: 1.1.2
map: Can not find required map name.

Press ESC in x seconds to skip startup.nsh, any other key to continue.
Shell> _
```

This error is because the EFI-partion is on the original drive. I cannot press any key at startup (USB keyboard doesn't work), can't do anything.

Came up with the idea to clone the EFI partition on an USB drive, create another bootable partition with the BIOS update utility and flash it. After flashing the BIOS, copy the EFI partion to the original drive and replace the temp drive with the original and boot from USB to install another OS.

The question is, is this possible anyway because I don't have a mSata to SATA adapter and need to purchase it but is it worth to do so. Does my plan going to work anyway.

Maybe there is another way to get root access to the thing, any ideas?

Comment: If it will read an EFI partition from USB, then you didn't need that mSATA adapter, because any of the USB ports would have worked (you just needed to disconnect the mSATA with the existing EFI partition)

Comment: @BenVoigt Hai, thanks for your reply. Despite your comment I don't know exactly what you mean. Can you explain it a little what you exactly pointing at? I cannot use the USB connection, I will use another computer to copy stuff.

Comment: I mean, if the existing BIOS refuses to boot from USB, then you may not be able to use a USB flash drive to pull this off, you may need a spare mSATA drive.

Comment: @BenVoigt The BIOS refuses to boot from USB, that is why I use the adapter (see also picture) above Inside this adapter I use a SD USB drive adapter ;-) with SD card that can be easily removed to format etc. It simulates a drive or is this not correct? Do you think it doesn't boot when I was able to copy the EFI partition of the original drive to the SD-card? Do you mean I need a real drive, exactly the same drive?

Comment: I mean the USB port you have there is no different from the USB ports on the outside of your case.  The adapter doesn't change the USB flash drive into a SATA drive.  It just connects the two USB data pins to the two USB data pins on the mini connector... the BIOS will see a USB drive, not a SATA drive.  I don't see any reason that you would need the exact same model of drive... but if your BIOS is locked to only boot from SATA then you need SATA.

Comment: Aha, thanks, I understand. ;-) So this adapter makes no sense.

Comment: Actually I was a bit confused until I looked closer at your picture and saw that it says mPCIe.  The mPCIe slot has (depending on B key or M key) USB data pins, SATA data pins, and PCI Express data pins.  Your adapter brings out the USB data pins to a standard USB connector.  It won't look like a SATA drive to the BIOS.

Comment: @BenVoigt Okay, I understand. But do you think what I try to do is possible with use of a spare drive?

Comment: What you propose sounds completely reasonable, and if you have spare USB sticks lying around I would try those first, just in case the BIOS doesn't actually block boot from USB, just tries SATA first.  I don't think you necessarily need to hook up an adapter to your old drive and clone it either... the partition scheme for EFI is quite well known and lots of documentation just a google search away (e.g. search for "create EFI system partition on USB stick")

Comment: @BenVoigt Very interesting info Ben, really appreciate it. So if I had a mSATA to SATA -> to USB adapter and replace the boot partition (leaving EFI partion intact) on another computer I am in. That's actually the only thing I have to do.

Comment: Yeah, if it doesn't look at USB even when the mSATA drive is pulled out, then rewriting (on the same or a different drive that is also mSATA) the boot files is probably required.  Since the drive capacity is so small, you should be able to make a complete backup of it onto another computer (provided you have the adapter to plug it in).

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the help, i will get such adapter. Nice to know that I doesn't have to throw it away because it is a nice little machine still usable for projects. I will try this however take some time (delivery). Again, thanks for the info.